# How can I T splice a 120V line in a lighting fixture?

Tags: electrical, lighting, splicing

I'm designing a recessed lighting fixture and would like to T splice some of the wires in it. The wires are 14AWG, will carry up to 4AMP and I'm looking to make an elegant connection so that it fits into the thin enclosing.

Is it ok to use a [T-Splicing of this kind](http://www.backinblackgp.com/Tap_And_Splice.htm), and cover the splice with liquid tape or plain electrical tape? The splice will be at the top of the lighting fixture, but may get some dust as a result of not being covered, but rather being in a channel.

Comment: If you are planning to use those T splice connections be aware that these are made for use in stranded wire -- not solid wire.

Comment: Regardless of your splicing method, it must be enclosed in an accessible junction box. It cannot be open on top of the fixture.

Comment: Most light fixtures will just run all the wires up to the electrical box, and make the connections in there.

Comment: @Steven, I think you're misunderstanding the situation. Lights with many sockets/lamps etc. have internal wiring and connections that aren't intended for the user to make. Vanity strip, dome, multi-pendant, multi-ballast fixtures to name a few will typically have 1+ taps made for you. It may happen but *"most"* certainly isn't the case. It's also bad design. The manufacturer of the light doesn't know what box the light will go and forcing the user to put additional wires in the box needlessly is problematic.

Comment: @Matthew, that's not true. I can go to HD, or any lighting supply house for that matter, and show you *many* fixtures where the wires are not tapped inside and *are* on top the fixture. Hell, I could take pics of at least four fixtures that are that way in my house now. Sounds like you're too broadly applying typical wiring methods to the internals of a fixture.

Comment: For future readers, this can be cleared up in 410.56(D) Splices and Taps : No *unnecessary* splices or taps shall be made *within* or **on** a luminaire. Unnecessary is the operative word there. It's far better to tap multiple wires inside or on a fixture than it is to run multiples to the box. Fill is an issue and so is the fact it's a loop. If one somehow works it's way off the main tap in the box it won't, as it would normally, de-energize the other wire(s). Instead there will be a loose hot conductor in possibly a plastic box.

Answer (score 1):

As I interpret the code, no. That "T" splice isn't allowed, and not really elegant IMHO.

```
2011 NEC
110.14 Electrical Connections
(B) Splices.
Conductors shall be spliced or joined with splicing devices identified for the use 
or by brazing, welding, or soldering with a fusible metal or alloy.
...
```

Where the article says you *could* solder the joint, in your case it's *shall* solder the joint. As far as the taps being in a approved enclosure, I can't agree with the commentary. Just go to any lighting store and you will see lights that have fixture wires on top of a light that would be much larger than any typical box. However, I'm not a manufacturer, I just have experience hanging a ton of lights.

Comment: I've never seen that type of connector used other than in  vehicle applications, though they do appear to be UL listed. At any rate, I think the OP is asking about the second method that's talked about in the linked article. It also sounds like they plan to make the connection outside of a box.

Comment: @Chief-Two-Pencils Not sure what you mean by "push the metal tap straight down". The taping/liquid taping is to create an insulation rather than holding it together.

Comment: @Tester101 thats kinda what I'm worried about, using it for a home light fixture, outside of an electrical box and not in a car applicaiton

Comment: @DinaNeishtadt You definitely don't want to make connections outside of an approved enclosure. Also, making a physical connection and wrapping it in tape, is not a good idea. Tape has a tendency to not hold up well over time, and could lead to exposed wires.

Comment: @Tester101 I'm designing a new light fixture, that has a number of canes, so it can't be in an approved enclosure, as the light fixture is the enclosure I'm designing....

Comment: @DinaNeishtadt, sorry I misunderstood. Please see the edit.

Comment: @Tester101, they're fine for electrical use. They're especially nice if you have a run of channel fixtures end-to-end. You pull your wire through and never have to make taps. They're, or should be limited though. I wouldn't/haven't used them outside of lighting fixtures. Yes, they're asking about the other, I've updated the answer, thanks.

Comment: @Chief-Two-Pencils not sure I fully understood you again... apologies! It seems like you are saying something very valuable so I want to make sure I understand you properly. I'm ok to use a tap connection in a lighting fixture body, enclosed in in, but with a wide ventilation opening, only if I solder them? And for insulation the tap I can use either an electrical tape or a liquid electrical tape, as long as I solder the tap connection and not only twist it?

Comment: @DinaNeishtadt, sorry about that. I'm saying, yes you can make taps in a lighting fixture body. The part where you're talking about ventilation I think refers to where I spoke of the size of a fixture. I'm responding to the idea that tabs should be made in an approved enclosure, which is generally true. However, lights, specifically fixture *wires* have special permissions untypical from day-to-day wiring. I was pointing out that you may have a 12" dome light attached to a 4" box so part of the wires will not be in an enclosure per-say. Unless it's HID ballasts I doubt you'd need ventilation.

Comment: @DinaNeishtadt, as far as the tap goes I'd say electrical tape that is identified for tap-wrapping. Cheap-o tape is actually *not* used on taps, it's more of a utility tape. I would actually caution against it. Speaking as a customer, the last word that would come to my mind if I saw taped joints on fixture wires is elegant; dangerous would come much sooner. I'd probably re-wire it honestly. But, yes, that's the idea. You could make that "T", although I doubt it's needed or required, and solder it and tape it up. I hope I was clearer here. Let me know if I can help further.

Comment: @DinaNeishtadt, just to be clear, when I say you can I mean thousands of manufacturers do it. Now, that may be a mandatory process of some type to get your fixture approved, like I said I'm not a light manufacturer. The risk of doing it without verifying could lead to responsibility for damage done as a result of your work. That's also a good reason not to tape and solder joints.

Comment: @Chief-Two-Pencils this is very helpful, thank you!